# Last background process ID ($!) not working in sudo bash command

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

Do shell variables work inside sudo executed commands?

I'm trying to run, and later kill, a background process, as another user inside a script.
However, I cannot capture the background process ID, with "$!", which means I cannot later kill the process.

Here is a simple example I've put together to illustrate:

```
#!/bin/bash
userOfThisScript=`id -u -n $SUDO_USER`

sudo -u $userOfThisScript /bin/bash << EOBLOCK
    vi &
    echo "BG Task ID inside block:  <$!>" # <-- $! is empty string
    kill $!
EOBLOCK
```

Running the background process works fine.
Checking the process executed (e.g. with "ps") I can confirm that the process is indeed owned by the user given to sudo.
However, the $! variable is just an empty string (as far as I can tell).

If I remove the sudo/bash block and just execute the process and kill it, then all works as expected with a correct process ID stored in $!.

Anyone have any idea why $! does not work inside this sudo/bash command execution?

(I'm using Linux/Ubuntu distros, 14.04 and 16.04.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here documents with an unquoted delimiter undergo variable expansion. Therefore, `$!` is interpreted in the context of the outer script, not the shell that runs the commands from the here document.

Either quote the `<< 'EOBLOCK'`, or backslash the dollar signs in the here document: `kill \$!`.

Comment: Makes sense.  Perfect, both approaches work.  Thanks very much!